# error MSB3073 ................... exited with code 8

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I was developing a code in Visual Studio C++ 2013. I am facing the following issue in the cmake file (I think so)  i tried to search a lot about this code but am failiing to find a proper solution for this.

code of the runtest

`<!--*******************************************************************************************
        Build Events
       ******************************************************************************************* -->
  <PropertyGroup>`

`<_BuildSuffix>
:VCEnd</_BuildSuffix>
  </PropertyGroup>`

`<Target Name="PreBuildEvent"`

`Condition="'$(PreBuildEventUseInBuild)'!='false'">`

`<Message Text="Description: %(PreBuildEvent.Message)" Condition="'%(PreBuildEvent.Message)' != '' and '%(PreBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>`

`<Exec Command="%(PreBuildEvent.Command)$(_BuildSuffix)" Condition="'%(PreBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>
  </Target>`

`<Target Name="PreLinkEvent" Condition="'$(PreLinkEventUseInBuild)'!='false'">`

`<Message Text="Description: %(PreLinkEvent.Message)" Condition="'%(PreLinkEvent.Message)' != '' and '%(PreLinkEvent.Command)' != ''"/>`

`<Exec Command="%(PreLinkEvent.Command)$(_BuildSuffix)" Condition="'%(PreLinkEvent.Command)' != ''"/>
  </Target>`

 `<Target Name="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(PostBuildEventUseInBuild)'!='false'">`

`<Message Text="Description: %(PostBuildEvent.Message)" Condition="'%(PostBuildEvent.Message)' != '' and '%(PostBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>`

`<Exec Command="%(PostBuildEvent.Command)$(_BuildSuffix)" Condition="'%(PostBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>`

`</Target>`

One of the solution even suggested to run Visual Studio in Administrator mode, but it is not working in this case

Following is the error case i have a solution it builds successfully, but when i try to build RUN_TESTS it is showing following error:-

```
Error   1   error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\ctest.exe" --force-new-ctest-process -C Release
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 8. C:\Program Files 
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   132  
5   RUN_TESTS
```

Comment: How can anyone possibly help you with your code, when you don't show your code? It's ridiculous. Please add the non-working code to this question.

Comment: Seems to be incorrectly configured CMake Project. Post a minimal example which reproduces this issue.

Comment: In case that 8 is a standard Windows error code, 8 = ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY.

Comment: This is a common problem caused by Visual Studio; it is unlikely to be a problem with CMakeLists.txt or your C++ code. It is unfortunate that this question was improperly closed by people who do not understand the problem; the failure is in a script generated by VS or CTest. It is unlikely there is a minimal example of user code since the problem is not in the user's code.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using a script as the command. Try writing your script in a batch file and call that batch file as the command for RUN_TESTS.